# How to use messages.properties variables and html thymeleaf th:utext?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

So, I'm trying to internationalize my spring-boot application. I'm using i18n

```
th:utext=" ${'<i class=\'fas fa-plus\'></i>' + #{quality.projects.button.add}}"
```

i've tried some things around this but nothing works.

```
th:utext=" ${<i class=\'fas fa-plus\'></i> + #{quality.projects.button.add}}"

th:utext=" #{'<i class=\'fas fa-plus\'></i>' + {quality.projects.button.add}}"

th:utext=" ${'<i class=\'fas fa-plus\'></i>'} + #{quality.projects.button.add}"

th:utext="<i class=\'fas fa-plus\'></i> + #{quality.projects.button.add}"
```

Each time I got an

```
Error 500 [Internal Server Error] : An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/views/quality/projects/index.html]")


Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: " <i class='fas fa-plus'></i> + #{quality.projects.button.add}" (template: "views/quality/projects/index" - line 9, col 123)
```

I supposed that the syntax is not correct for thymeleaf template, but I don't know how can I get my text and html.

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share what you have tried, and what you mean by "_nothing works_"? What do you see in the page? What errors are generated?

Comment: I've edited the post

Comment: First step is to fix the parse errors - for example: `<div th:utext="${'<i class=&quot;fas fa-plus&quot;></i>'} + #{quality.projects.button.add}"></div>`. But this may lead to new errors if your properties file is not set up correctly.

Comment: Sorry - I realized you can simplify slightly - no need for that initial `${...}` - it's just a string literal `'...'`. So, this:  `<div th:utext="'<i class=&quot;fas fa-plus&quot;></i>' + #{quality.projects.button.add}"></div>`.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please be very careful when using `th:utext` because it opens up your code to cross-site scripting exploits - for example, if you include user-provided (and therefore untrusted) input inside the `th:utext`. In this specific case, you are only including your own hard-coded piece of HTML - so it's not a problem. But also, in this case, because the `th:utext` content is hard-coded, you don't actually need `th:utext` at all - and therefore you should be able to re-arrange things, and remove it completely.

Comment: But how can I put html if i remove the 'th:utext'  ? How would you do ? Maybe with a span inside ?

Comment: Exactly - yes - with a span. That is one way to re-arrange things.